# How to prevent a subscriber from entering multiple journeys at the same time in Journey Builder?

Tags: journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio, marketing-cloud

We have multiple journeys built using journey builder in our SFMC instance. We are trying to enforce a new business rule which should prevent the same subscriber from entering multiple journeys at the same time? i.e. A subscriber should be active in only one journey at a time.

Was wondering what would be the best/simplest way to implement this rule? The only way that I can think of is by using sql queries to filter against subscribers (in the entry source DE) who are currently active in other journeys.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no data view readily available showing you contacts currently in journeys. You could engage with Salesforce professional service to have one built. This will allow you to query exactly who is in which journey and since what date.

Not having such a data view, you have only a single solution left, and it is working with Update Contact Activities, writing journey status in a data extension. [Here is a good example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_the_update_contact_data_activity.htm&type=5) of how this can be used. You should place an Update Contact Activity immediately after the entry, and just before the final wait step prior to exit in every branch.

Please be aware, that in cases where a contact exits the journey prematurely, due to either meeting the goal or exit criteria, he will not pass the final Update Contact Activity, and hence seem to be still within a journey. A housekeeping process in automation studio should be put in place, looking for contacts who seem to be in a specific journey for more than the expected duration of it, and set their status to exited.

You will be able to query the data extension updated by these activities, and use this info to exclude specific contacts from entering other journeys with Data Extension entry events.

Comment: Do you know why this data isn't GA? Both that and mapping of ContactKey and ContactId would make life so much easier.

Comment: Well - there are tons of data within SFMC which is not exposed in e.g data views - for one reason or another. Guessing why this is the case, is not easy. I can't say if such a journey presence data view will be provided OOTB in the future, however I know that journey orchestration is in high demand with many of my clients.

Comment: The link to the Salesforce article no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of update contact activity.

1. Create a new boolean attributes in the data extension.
2. Add update contact activity in all the journeys at entry of the journey set the boolean as 'True' and add at the exit as well and set the boolean as 'False'
3. In the journey main filter criteria or in decision split you can check if this is false then enter the journey

This is the easiest way without using SQL query.

Hope this helps!